# Create a dynamic table with DT::datatable in flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, flexdashboard

I have a follow `RMarkdown` file:

````
---
title: "Table"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(
  n = 6, expr = runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 100)
  ), 
  y = as.factor(x = sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE)), 
  z = rep(letters[1:10], each = 3)
)
```

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
```

DataTable
====================================

###
```{r}
datatable(data = df_1, 
          options = list(pageLength = 10, lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30), 
                         autoWidth = TRUE, columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', 
targets = "_all"))), 
              filter = "top", rownames = FALSE, caption = "Customer sum", selection = 
'single') %>% 
  formatRound(columns = 1:6, digits = 1) %>% 
  formatCurrency(columns = 1:6, currency = "$ ")
```
````

How to sum columns from `x.1` to `x.6` (for each column), always updating with the filters of `y` and `z`?

- I want to create a total for each column, even applying the filters. Like this:

[image]

I know that there are solutions with `shiny`, only. But I need to apply this to `flexdashboard`.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need `df_1 %>% group_by(y, z) %>% summarise_at(vars(starts_with('x')), sum)`  or if you are doing it separately `df_1. %>% filter(y == input$y, z === input$z) %>%  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('x')), sum)`

Comment: I need this sum to be made within the web application.

Comment: yes, can you please check my updated comment